# UIView renderInContex specific position

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, pdf-generation, quartz-graphics

In my app I need to create a PDF. This PDF must have a layout with some boxes where user will write text inside.

My problem is the layers have always origin 0,0 (x,y) while I want to draw the boxes at specific positions in the pdf.

Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)genPdf:(id)sender {
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100) ];
    aView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    aView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    aView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;           

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = @"test.pdf";
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:documentsDirectory, filename, nil]];

    // Create PDF context
    CGRect pdfSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 420, 596); 
    CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, &pdfSize, NULL);
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
    UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
    // Flip coordinate system
    CGRect bounds = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(pdfContext);
    CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);

    // Drawing commands
    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext]; // should be origin.x and .y 10,10 but is 0,0!!!!

    // Clean up
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
    CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);

}
```

Thanks for help.

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just translate the context to the view's origin with `CGContextTranslateCTM`. You may also want to use `drawInContext` in order to produce vectorized rather than rasterized output.

Comment: I found a simple way changing the UIViews bounds.